# gridview button with databound drop down fails

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with a button, and when the button is clicked, it fires a rowcommand procedure and adds a new row to the database. Everything works fine until I add a databound drop down list to the gridview.

With a databound dropdown list, the page loads fine, but when I click the button the error shows as "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". here is my code

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="insertNew"  
    Text="Button" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="insertNew"
                CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                Text="Add" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is my code behind that runs when the button is pressed;

```
   Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If (e.CommandName = "insertNew") Then

        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        MsgBox(index)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `MsgBox` line.  `MsgBox(index)` is not supported in web applications.

Please remove `MsgBox(index)`, and the issue will be fixed, because that feature is only supported in Windows Applications.

Comment: i just had that in there on my localhost, where it does work. it doesnt matter what is in there.

Comment: It doesnt make any difference what is in the procedure, when there is a databound drop down list in the grid it fails. BTW, you can use msgbox locally.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put this into the system.web web.config file

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
```